# Partial derivative in different basis

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

In my textbook, partial derivatives are defined as follows:

> Let $f : U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $\hat{x}_0\in\text{int} (U)$. If $x_1, \dots, x_n$  denote the variables determined by an orthonormal basis $\{\hat{e}_1, \dots, \hat{e}_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we define the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the variable $x_i$ as:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} := \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(\hat{x}_0 + h\hat{e}_i)-f(\hat{x}_0)}{h}$$

Also this exercise is from the same textbook:

> Let $\hat{e}_1, \dots, \hat{e}_n$ be an orthonomal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f: U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ exists for all $\hat{x}\in U$, with $i\in\{1, \dots n\}$, and is continuous. If $x'_1, \dots, x'_n$ is another coordinate system determined by an orthonoraml basis $\{\hat{e}'_1, \dots, \hat{e}'_n\}$, show that the exists $j\in\{1,\dots, n\}$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'_j}$ exists for all $\hat{x}\in U$ and is continuous.

Can you give me a hint to start the proof? I have no idea how to start it.

Comment: I presume your textbook proved that a continuous function with continuous partial derivatives must be differentiable, so you can use a convenient formula for directional derivatives.

Comment: @TedShifrin The exercise only says that one partial derivative exist, it doesn't ensure that all of them exist.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t interpret $i$ as fixed. Then the claim seems very false. Try to give a counterexample with $n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false, consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by:

\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{split}
0 \hspace{1cm} &x \not=0\\
 -1 \hspace{1cm} &x =0
\end{split}
\right.
\end{equation*}

If $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ then

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0, y_0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f((0,y_0) + he_2)- f(0, y_0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0,y_0+ h) + 1}{h} = 0$$

if $x_0\not=0$ then

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f((x_0,y_0) + he_2)- f(x_0, y_0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0,y_0+ h)}{h} = 0$$

So $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist for all $\hat{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and is continuous. Now, consider the basis:

$$\{e'_1 = (1/\sqrt2, 1/\sqrt2), \ e'_2=(-1/\sqrt2, 1/\sqrt2)\}$$

we get that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}(0, 0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(he_1)- f(0, 0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h/\sqrt{2},h/\sqrt{2}) + 1}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}(0, 0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(he_2)- f(0, 0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(-h/\sqrt{2},h/\sqrt{2}) + 1}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}$$

So $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}(0, 0)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}(0, 0)$ don't exist.

Comment: You can modify this to give a continuous counterexample, too.